Why this inner atomic block not rolled back in a viewflow custom view code
I created this custom create process view to add in logged in user's email to the saved object, I also added a transaction block so that when the next step fails (inside self.activation_done() statement) it will roll back the db changes inside form_valid() and then display the error in the start step, so no new process instance is saved.
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import transaction
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from viewflow.flow.views import CreateProcessView, StartFlowMixin


class StarterEmailCreateProcessView(CreateProcessView):
    """
    Sets the user email to the process model
    """
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model and finish the task."""
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                super(StartFlowMixin, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
                # begin of setting requester email
                # https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/issues/314
                self.object.requester_email = self.request.user.email
                self.object.save()
                # end of setting requester email
                self.activation_done(form, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as ex:
            form.add_error(None, ValidationError(str(ex)))
            return self.form_invalid(form, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

Based on Django documentation, exception raised inside the transaction is rolled back

However, upon form displays the error message, new process instances are still saved, so I suspect the transaction is not rolled back and I don't know why.
UPDATE:
If I raise exception right before self.activation_done, it rolls back fine, I don't know what's so special inside self.activation_done that prevented the rollback?
class StarterEmailCreateProcessView(CreateProcessView):
    """
    Sets the user email to the process model
    """
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model and finish the task."""
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                super(StartFlowMixin, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
                # begin of setting requester email
                # https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/issues/314
                self.object.requester_email = self.request.user.email
                self.object.save()
                # end of setting requester email
                raise Exception('11111111111')
                self.activation_done(form, *args, **kwargs)
                
        except Exception as ex:
            form.add_error(None, ValidationError(str(ex)))
            return self.form_invalid(form, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

I even tried the following, it caught the exception but not rolled back.
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        """If the form is valid, save the associated model and finish the task."""
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                super(StartFlowMixin, self).form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
                # begin of setting requester email
                # https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/issues/314
                self.object.requester_email = self.request.user.email
                self.object.save()
                # end of setting requester email
                try:
                    self.activation_done(form, *args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    raise Exception(1111111)
        except Exception as ex:
            form.add_error(None, ValidationError(str(ex)))
            return self.form_invalid(form, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

UPDATE 2
I went into the source code of activation.done and commented out the lock logic, and it rolls back fine
    @Activation.status.transition(source=STATUS.PREPARED, target=STATUS.DONE)
    def done(self):
        """
        Create and start new process instance.

        .. seealso::
            :data:`viewflow.signals.task_started`

        .. seealso::
             :data:`viewflow.signals.task_finished`

        .. seealso::
            :data:`viewflow.signals.flow_started`

        """
        with transaction.atomic(savepoint=True):
            signals.task_started.send(sender=self.flow_class, process=self.process, task=self.task)

            self.process.save()

            # lock_impl = self.flow_class.lock_impl(self.flow_class.instance)
            # self.lock = lock_impl(self.flow_class, self.process.pk)
            # self.lock.__enter__()

            self.task.process = self.process
            self.task.finished = now()
            self.task.save()

            signals.task_finished.send(sender=self.flow_class, process=self.process, task=self.task)
            signals.flow_started.send(sender=self.flow_class, process=self.process, task=self.task)

            self.activate_next()

lock implementation, haven't wrapped my head around how this preventes the rollback yet.
class NoLock(object):
    """
    No pessimistic locking, just execute flow task in transaction.

    Not suitable when you have Join nodes in your flow.
    """

    def __call__(self, flow):
        @contextmanager
        def lock(flow_class, process_pk):
            with transaction.atomic():
                yield
        return lock

no_lock = NoLock()


The self.lock.__enter__() looked suspicious without exiting, so I changed it to become the following and it rolled back as expected
        with transaction.atomic(savepoint=True):
            signals.task_started.send(sender=self.flow_class, process=self.process, task=self.task)

            self.process.save()

            lock_impl = self.flow_class.lock_impl(self.flow_class.instance)
            self.lock = lock_impl(self.flow_class, self.process.pk)
            # self.lock.__enter__()
            with self.lock:
                self.task.process = self.process
                self.task.finished = now()
                self.task.save()

                signals.task_finished.send(sender=self.flow_class, process=self.process, task=self.task)
                signals.flow_started.send(sender=self.flow_class, process=self.process, task=self.task)

                self.activate_next()

@kmmbvnr can you please verify? Is there going to be any unintended consequences after this change?
I see similar usage in viewflow v2 here
https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/main/viewflow/workflow/nodes/start.py#L33
